# griddedInterpolant Alternative in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a command

```
griddedInterpolant({ANT.vValArrayFactor, ANT.uValArrayFactor},rot90(AF,2),'linear')
```

This was a command being used in Matlab 2012a but I need to get a similar command that works in Matlab 2007a

Options?

Answer (score 1):

Before there was griddedInterpolant, there was INTERPN.